# PHP | header gets set in catch block without exception

Tags: php, exception, header, try-catch

Okay I have this weird problem.

I want to set the header to 401 - Unauthorized if the try block throws an exception.

```
try {
    $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
    var_dump($decoded);
} catch (Exception $e) {        
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
}
```

But even if the try block doesn't throw an exception the header gets set anyway.

If I try to print out the exception message using

```
try {
    $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
    var_dump($decoded);
} catch (Exception $e) {        
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

`var_dump($decoded)` gets printed.

TLTR:
The header gets set even if the try block doesn't throw an exception.

Edit:
I found out that the problem only exists in my local project.
I'm using xampp, any ideas?

Edit²: Okay. I found out that it doesn't work with CORS. Can anyone tell me how to properly enable CORS?

My .htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, content-type, accept, Authorization"
```

Error message: CORS Request blocked: [...]  CORS-Preflight-Channel was not successful.

Comment: Not possible - what is possible is that your browser is caching a previous header from the same page

Comment: I cleared the cache, still 401.